# PopupWindow Dim Background in Android 6 (Marshmallow)

Tags: android, popupwindow, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am using the following code script to do dim background for Android PopupWindow.It is working well for the android version except version 6 (Marshmallow).

It throws "Cannot cast FrameLayout.LayoutParams to WindowManager.LayoutParams"

How to solve this problem for Android version 6.I dont want to use Dialog.

```
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(contentView, width, height);
popup.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
popup.showAsDropDown(anchor);

WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams p = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) contentView.getLayoutParams();
p.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
p.dimAmount = 0.3f;
wm.updateViewLayout(contentView, p);
```

Comment: You can see this:
[Android M ClassCastException: FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to WindowManager$LayoutParams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093254/android-m-classcastexception-framelayoutlayoutparams-cannot-be-cast-to-windowm/36093353#36093353)

Comment: You can use `contentView.getRootView().getLayoutParams()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use custome dialog instead of popup window. popup window create problem in android 6. You can do everything like popup window in custom dialog.
just create a layout and inflate into dialog and you will get every property of dailog. here is code.

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
  dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //for remove default title
    dialog.setCancelable(false); //for canceal back button click 
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.payment_popup_window);

    ImageButton variable_name=(ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.xml_id);
    ImageButton variable_name2=(ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.xml_id2);
    Button variable_name3=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.xml_id3);
    variable_name1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //your code
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

   variable_name2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //your code
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    variable_name3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //for making dialog fit in android screen
```

Along this outside touch can't dismiss it. you can't get this in popup window in android 6.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. For Marshmallow and above, you need to add one more getParent() to access the container. Use the code below:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
    contentView = (View) pwindow.getContentView().getParent().getParent();
} else {
    contentView = (View) pwindow.getContentView().getParent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Android M and above:

```
public static void controlPopupDim(PopupWindow popupWindow, boolean showing) {
    View parent = popupWindow.getContentView().getRootView();
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
    wlp.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
    wlp.dimAmount = showing ? 0.5f : 0f;
    if (wm != null) {
        wm.updateViewLayout(parent, wlp);
    }
}
```

You basically need to call it with `true` when you call the `showAsDropDown` on your popup and `false` when the popup is dismissed (may be via the `onDismissListener`)