# FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to WindowManager$LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-popupwindow

I am facing the similar issue explained in this link below. But the solution is not posted . Please help with the solution .

[Android M ClassCastException: FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to WindowManager$LayoutParams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093254/android-m-classcastexception-framelayoutlayoutparams-cannot-be-cast-to-windowm/36093353#36093353)

Comment: if you were reading the linked question and answer carefully you'd get the solution - change your implementation. Use a `DialogActivity` for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use a DialogActivity. Just add one more getParent() to access the container.

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
            container = (View) pwindow.getContentView().getParent().getParent();
        }else{
            container = (View) pwindow.getContentView().getParent();
        }
```