# Dimming an Activity when a FAB is clicked

Tags: java, android

I have been trying many solutions to dim the Activity background when the onClickListener of my FAB (FloatingActionButton) is clicked.

Here is my attempted code that doesn't work because I'm not sure what the 'parent' is:

```
m_fabContactOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            isFabExpanded = !isFabExpanded ;

            if (isFabExpanded ) {
                WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams p = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
                p.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
                p.dimAmount = 0.4f;
                wm.updateViewLayout(parent, p);
            }
            else {
                WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams p = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
                p.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
                p.dimAmount = 0.0f;
                wm.updateViewLayout(parent, p);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was creating a LinearLayout that fill the whole screen and setting the alpha to 0.5 (50% opacity) and making it hidden by default. When the button is clicked I just make it visible and when I need to hide it I remove it.

The LinearLayour Code is Below:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llDim"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set activity dim , first of all you can put id to xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/parentLayout">
```

define in your class this layout,

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
```

and you can get layout params of this element,

```
LayoutParams params=parent.getLayoutParams();
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448832/framelayoutlayoutparams-cannot-be-cast-to-windowmanagerlayoutparams

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParams.dimAmount = 0.75f;
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```